# How can I fix : Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image to Cloudinary from my local address (localhost:3000). However, when I try upload an image to it, it is giving me this error:
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dz8xmxmly/image/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-access-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**
Here is my code -

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Input = (props) => {
const uploadImage = (event) => {
const file = event.target.files[0];
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("upload_preset", "lwop0fgy");
axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dz8xmxmly/image/upload", formData)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data.url);
})}
return (
<>
<input  type="file" onChange = {uploadImage} />
</>
 );
 };
 export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issues while writing my first application.
CORS - Cross Access Resource Sharing
Applicable when you try to fetch/put data from other domains.

Preflight request - request which browser makes behalf of you at the backend server to check whether you are elligible/authorized to make CRUD operations (for put,delete,post) requests only.

At backend `Cloudinary` has allowed only requests with certain headers which are not there in your post request
eg, `Cloudinary` does not allow `x-access-token` which you are trying to send.

But I am not sure from where exactly you are setting up headers in axios.

You might change your code to the following

```
    axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dz8xmxmly/image/upload",formdata,{
    headers:{
       //read cloudinary documentation and write approproate headers here 
    }
    })
    .then((res)=>{
       //do something
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      //do somehting
    })
```

[Please refer to this post](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4403367324562-Error-Cors-when-fetching-image-api) for additional information.

Comment: I have not added any headers to my code. what can I include in my headers? I tried to read their documentation but was not helpful.

Comment: [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference) you can find api docs for cloudinary which has all the information require.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", files[0]);
formData.append("upload_preset", "sdfsfuyi");

const instance = axios.create();
instance.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/
v1_1/cloud_name/image/upload", formData)
```

Note the `const instance = axios.create();`